# Variable "studentNumber" and "passWord" might no have been initialized?

Tags: android, variables

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public EditText studentNumber, passWord;
//defining AwesomeValidation object
public AwesomeValidation awesomeValidation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    awesomeValidation = new AwesomeValidation(ValidationStyle.BASIC);
    studentNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.studentNumber);
    passWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passWord);

    awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.studentNumber, "^[0-9]{9}", R.string.studentnumberError);
    String regexPassword = ".{8,}";
    awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.passWord, regexPassword, R.string.invalid_password);

    signIn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

// Triggers when LOGIN Button clicked
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == signIn) {
        checkLogin();
    }
}

public void checkLogin() {

    // Get text from studentNumber and passWord field
    final String studentNumber = studentNumber.getText().toString();
    final String passWord = passWord.getText().toString();

    // Initialize  AsyncLogin() class with studentNumber and password
    new AsyncLogin().execute(studentNumber,passWord);

    }
}
```

Android Studio says that the variables studentNumber and passWord are might not have been initialized. The error shows on this line:

```
final String studentNumber = studentNumber.getText().toString();
final String passWord = passWord.getText().toString();
```

What seems to be the problem? Is it the validation of the form? Thank you.

Comment: Change variable name of your strings. The variable names are conflicting.

Comment: I have also given answer. Please refer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are getting Error because the String name and edittext name are sample please change your method like this.

```
public void checkLogin() {

    // Get text from studentNumber and passWord field
    final String studentNum = studentNumber.getText().toString();
    final String pass= passWord.getText().toString();

    // Initialize  AsyncLogin() class with studentNumber and password
    new AsyncLogin().execute(studentNum,pass);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your string variable name in onClick method, It is conflicting with edittext variable name:

```
public void checkLogin() {

// Get text from studentNumber and passWord field
final String studentNumberString = studentNumber.getText().toString();
final String passWordString = passWord.getText().toString();

// Initialize  AsyncLogin() class with studentNumber and password
new AsyncLogin().execute(studentNumberString,passWordString);

}
}
```

Comment: You could also pass it directly as method parameters since storing them in a final field has no value there.

Comment: Yeah. Correct. There are numerous ways for this.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting **Variable “studentNumber” and “passWord” might no have been initialized?**

> because your String variable name and your Edit-text name both are same so they are conflicting

just change your String variable name

use this

```
final String studentNumber2 = studentNumber.getText().toString();
final String passWord2 = passWord.getText().toString();
```

instead of this

```
final String studentNumber = studentNumber.getText().toString();
final String passWord = passWord.getText().toString();
```